# User table with users following other users in Amplify

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I'm new to GraphQL and Amplify, and I basically want to accomplish this from the cli:

```
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  follows: [User]
}
```

So a user can follow other users, and I want to be able to add users to follow to a user, get a list of the users a user follows, and also list all the users who follows a specific user. I would guess this quite basic setup shuold be possible quite easily from the cli as I have been able to setup other such relations (but between different types), however, this (maybe naive) schema does not give me the mutations and queries I would like when running `amplify push api`.

What is the best way to accomplish what I want?